# ValidationError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value 'X' (type string) at path '_id' - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to seed my mongodb database and I am running into this Validation error.

the error:

```
ValidationError: food validation failed: _id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type string) at path "_id" because of "BSONError"
    at model.Document.invalidate (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:3157:32)
    at model.$set (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1453:12)
    at model.set (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/document/compile.js:205:19)
    at model.idSetter (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/schema/idGetter.js:41:12)
    at VirtualType.applySetters (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/virtualtype.js:166:16)
    at model.$set (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1271:12)
    at model.$set (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1113:16)
    at model.Document (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:164:12)
    at model.Model (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:122:12)
    at new model (/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4682:15)
```

my model.ts looks like:

```
export interface Food {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    tags: string[];
    favorite: boolean;
    stars: number;
    imageUrl: string;
    origins: string[];
    cookTime: string;
    url: string;
}

export const FoodSchema = new Schema<Food>(
    {
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        price: {type: Number, required: true},
        tags: {type: [String], required: true},
        favorite: {type: Boolean, default: false},
        stars: {type: Number, required: true},
        imageUrl: {type: String, required: true},
        origins: {type: [String], required: true},
        cookTime: {type: String, required: true},
        url: {type: String, required: true},
    }, {
        toJSON: {
            virtuals: true
        },
        toObject: {
            virtuals: true
        },
        timestamps: true
    }
);

export const FoodModel = model<Food>('Food', FoodSchema);
```

and my seed api looks like:

```
router.get("/seed", asynceHandler(
    async (req,res)=>{
        const foodsCount = await FoodModel.countDocuments();
        if(foodsCount>0){
            res.send("Seed is already done");
            return;
        }
        await FoodModel.create(sample_foods);
        res.send("Seed is done")
    }
))
```

What am I doing wrong? I am a newbie to Mongodb and trying to learn it with the help of a tutorial.

Comment: Which line throws this error? Show the full error stack, and what do you get `console.log(sample_foods)`.

Comment: I updated the full error stack here, the sample_foods just contains mock data as an array of objects. like:

`{
      id:'1',
      name: 'Pizza Pepperoni',
      cookTime: '10-20',
      price: 10,
      favorite: false,
      origins: ['italy'],
      stars: 4.5,
      imageUrl: 'assets/food-1.jpg',
      tags: ['FastFood', 'Pizza', 'Lunch'],
      url: '/food/1'
    },`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id: '1'` is not a valid id. The valid Id can be a 24 character hex string, 12 byte binary Buffer, or a number. Mongoose cast the `id: '1'` to an ObjectId failed, that's why you got the error.

How does cast work? Mongoose will try to create the ObjectId using `new bson.ObjectId('1')`, in the `ObjectId` constructor, it will validate the input id and throw a [BSONError](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/c0086c9bc3433127fda1bea7aa02a45549114b27/src/objectid.ts#L89)

You have three choices:

If you want to use the `_id` Mongoose added to the document, do:

- create the ObjectId explicitly using `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`
- Let the mongoose create ObjectId for you. You don't need to pass the `id` field to the `Food.create()` method.

If you want to create an `id` field by yourself, do:

- Declare an `id` field with a `String` type in the schema. But you have to maintain its uniqueness with a [unique indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-on-a-single-field).

E.g.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
console.log(mongoose.version);

const FoodSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // id: String
    name: String,
});
const Food = mongoose.model('Food', FoodSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        // seed
        const sample_foods = {
            id: '1',
            name: 'Pizza Pepperoni',
        };
        // create ObjectId explicitly
        // await Food.create({ ...sample_foods, id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() });

        // create ObjectId implicitly
        const { id, ...rest } = sample_foods;
        await Food.create(rest);

        // declare an id field with the String type, then `id: '1'` is ok.
        // await Food.create(sample_foods);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me to understand!